# Component stylesheets

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

A bunch of years back I wrote a [reasonably functional IDE](https://github.com/b3m2a1/EasyIDE?tab=readme-ov-file) for Mathematica development in Mathematica, which required me to tackle a bunch of thorny theming issues

In particular, I consistently came across the problem that I would want to define styles for individual elements of an interface that could be done in a mix-and-match way. Basically I wanted to be able to have a set of stylesheets for one given component (defined via `TemplateBox` structures) and one set of stylesheets for my overall notebook themes and didn't want to have to synthesize one global stylesheet from them

This is a classic inheritance-vs-composition issue, and six years ago I don't think there was a simple resolution. At a minimum, there was no multiple-inheritance type mechanism that would allow me to separate these components without making some kind of tree of stylesheets

Is it possible to do this these days? I.e. to have different styles for different components defined in separate stylesheets that can all be imported in one notebook?